# Ionic 2 - Tabs at the bootom for side menu pages

Tags: menu, tabs, ionic2

I want to have something like IONIC Conference App. Here is image flow about what I have and what I want to have. Any idea how can I solve this problem?

[image]

Comment: so what is the issue? https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-conference-app

Comment: Add the relative code snippets.

Answer (score 0):

Try import your support page to your tabs.ts page

```
import { SupportPage } from '../support/support';
```